# Laravel Auth redirects to Login after authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

I recently changed the Auth default table from users to employees now the problem i have is it keeps redirecting to login form after authentication.
the Auth::attempt method returns true but it keeps redirecting to login page.

```
defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],


'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'redirectTo' => 'employee.dashboard',
        'provider' => 'employees',
    ],
],


],


'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'employees' => [
        'provider' => 'employees',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],


'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

Comment: what guard are you using when using the `auth` middleware? your default guard is `web` which is using the `users` table ... you would need to be using the `empoloyees` guard if you want to use the other table

Answer (score 0):

in loginController file

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = '/panel';
    protected function redirectTo()
     {
        if (auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
            return '/admin';
        }
        return '/home';
     }

}
```

you can use `redirectTo`  property or method. the method overrides the property

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, forgot to change the default guard to employees. Also you have to pass the primary key in your model so that the session persist.